# Differential operators in $\Bbb R^n$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, differential-operators, pseudo-differential-operators

Put  $P_j=\frac{\partial}{\partial \xi_j}$ et $Q_j=2 i \xi_j$ with$\xi=\left(\xi_1, \ldots, \xi_n\right)$ et $x=\left(x_1, \ldots, x_n\right)$. How to prove :

1. $\exp \left(\sum_{j=1}^n x_j P_j\right)(f)(\xi)=f(\xi+x)$.
2. $\exp \left(\sum_{j=1}^n x_j Q_j\right)(f)(\xi)=\exp (2 i(x, \xi)) f(\xi)$.
   where $(x, \xi)=\sum_{j=1}^n x_j \xi_j$ and $i^2=-1$.
   Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I want first to change your notations, sticking to the usual variables $x,\xi$ in the phase space. As a general statement about pseudo-differential operator with a symbol $a(x,\xi)$, I wish to write
$$
\bigl(\text{Op}(a) f\bigr)(x)=\int e^{2iπ x\cdot \xi} a(x,\xi) \hat f(\xi) \, d\xi.
$$
Let $y\in \mathbb R^n$ be given. Then we have
$$
f(x+y)=\int e^{2iπ (x+y)\cdot \xi}\hat f(\xi) \, d\xi
=
\int e^{2iπ x\cdot \xi}e^{2iπ y\cdot \xi}\hat f(\xi) \, d\xi=
\bigl(\operatorname{Op}(a_y) f\bigr)(x), \quad a_y(x,\xi)=e^{2iπ y\cdot \xi},
$$
which is your first formula.

Let $\eta\in \mathbb R^n$ be given. Then we have
$$
e^{2iπ x\cdot \eta}f(x)=\int e^{2iπ x\cdot \xi}e^{2iπ x\cdot \eta}\hat f(\xi) \, d\xi=\bigl(\text{Op}(b_\eta) f\bigr)(x),\quad b_\eta(x,\xi)=e^{2iπ x\cdot \eta},
$$
and this is your second formula.

Comment: Thank you a lot.